# Selecting first n observations of each group

Tags: r

I and my coworkers enter data in turns. One day I do, the next week someone else does and we always enter 50 observations at a time (into an Excel sheet). So I can be pretty sure that I entered the cases from 101 to 150, and 301 to 350. We then read the data into R to work with it. How can I select only the cases I entered?

Now I know that I can do that by copying from the excel sheet, however, I wonder if it is doable in R?

I checked several documents about subsetting data with R, also tried things like

```
data<-data[101:150 & 301:350,]
```

but didn't work. I appreciate if someone would guide me to a more comprehensive guide answering this question.

Comment: `data[c(100:150,300:350),]` .  Can you be more specific about which cases you want?  Is it the first 50 of each 100, or the first 50 of each 300, or ... ?  The first `n` of each `m` would be something like `c(outer(0:4,seq(0,100,by=10),"+"))` (here `n`=5, `m`=10)

Comment: "cases from 100 to 150" covers 51 observations

Comment: @Ben Bolker Thank you for overanswering my question. It made me realize that I should work on basic concepts like collections and vectors. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Henry Thank you for highlighting this obvious mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the specific example you gave is

```
data[c(100:150,300:350),]
```

Can you be more specific about which cases you want? Is it the first 50 of each 100, or the first 50 of each 300, or ... ? To get the indices for the  first `n` of each `m` cases you could use something like

```
c(outer(0:4,seq(1,100,by=10),"+"))
```

(here `n`=5, `m`=10); `outer` is a generalized outer product.  An alternate (and possibly more intuitive) solution would use `rep`, e.g.

```
rep(0:4,10) + rep(seq(1,100,by=10),each=5)
```

Because R automatically recycles vectors where necessary you could actually shorten this to:

```
0:4 + rep(seq(1,100,by=10),each=5)
```

but I would recommend the slightly longer formulation as more understandable.